# Bootstrap-Table: How to hide a column without deleting it from the DOM?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

I'm having problems with the Bootstrap-Table plugin:
https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table

I have a hidden ID column in the table I need to hide. But I can't do

```
<th data-field="id" data-visible="false">ID</th>
```

because that deletes it from the DOM. I need to **keep the ID in the DOM**, since it's used in form submission. It just needs to be hidden.

This doesn't work either, my style is lost and the column doesn't exist:

```
<th data-field="id" style="display:none;>ID</th>
```

I can't even use jQuery to hide the column manually! In other words, I tried the following after onPostBody, and it never fired either!

```
<table id="delegateTable"  data-toggle="table" data-url="delegates.action"
 data-response-handler="delegatesResponseHandler">
   <thead>
        <tr>
           <th data-field="id">ID</th>
           <th data-field="delegate" style="width:10%">Delegate</th>
   </thead>
</table>
```

jQuery Doc OnReady:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Hide column
    $('#delegateTable').bootstrapTable({
        onPostBody : function() {
            $('#delegateTable td:nth-child(0), th:nth-child(0)').hide();
            alert('column hidden');                 
        }
    });
```

It never even gets to that onPostBody.

Comment: why do you assume its deleted from the dom?

Comment: I check in Chrome Dev Tools (F12) and the column doesn't exist at all. Only N-1 columns exist. Both TD and TH

Comment: either some code is removing it, because hiding it does just that and nothing else, or something is faulty with your debugging

Comment: are you familiar with Bootstrap-Table or are you just talking randomly? I am not hiding anything, Bootstrap-Table is responsible for outputting all my columns.

Comment: Guys... it really removes it from the DOM: https://jsfiddle.net/pj3rpnxu/

Comment: randomly generally... here we go again with randomly, then the library is probably saving the content inside a object or something similiar, either retrieve the desired data or use a diffrent function to hide the data

http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best option would be

to change the data field to add the class

```
<th class="col-xs-1" data-class='hidden' data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
```

and of course css for the hidden class

```
.hidden{
  display:none;
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yhtgfawj/7/

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right, the problem is that your jQuery selector is wrong.

Css's `:nth-child` doesn't start at `0` ;)

This will work:

```
$('#delegateTable').bootstrapTable({
    onPostBody : function() {
        $('#delegateTable').find('th:nth-child(1), tr td:nth-child(1)').hide();
        alert('column hidden');                 
    }
});
```

See [this example.](https://jsfiddle.net/z9bwu9o4/)

You can also replace this javascript with CSS:

```
#delegateTable th:nth-child(1), #delegateTable tr td:nth-child(1){
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: but why did you have the CSS? When I remove your CSS for nth-child(1), it stops working. In theory I should be able to just .hide() without the CSS definitions, right? But the hide() alone doesn't work.

Comment: My bad, I forgot the CSS there and didn't see that it was the one making it work.

Comment: I have updated my answer now with the correct selector!

Comment: Weird, my onPostBody never fires and I never get to my alert messages. But I see that your Fiddle works. Thanks. will confirm shortly.

Comment: wouldn't recommend this solution will be problematic if you change column to hide, you'll have to change css everytime accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem putting class d-none of bootstrap in headdings and cels of columns that I want to hide but dont disappear from DOM

Answer (score 0):

Make that column have `width:0; overflow:hidden;` This will hide the column and still have it be in the DOM.

Comment: Nope -- that shows the column. Here, I've updated Phiter's JSFiddle to show how even putting a style on it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/pj3rpnxu/7/   (version **7**)  With your CSS, it will output the 'Stars' column.

Comment: @geneb. That's because you only put it on the header column. It's not applied to the cells inside the tbody. You have to apply it to those as well. So: `.tr td:nth-child(1), tr th:nth-child(1){ width:0; overflow:hidden;}`

Comment: But Bootstrap-Table doesn't give me control over TD's, only TABLE/TH. The rest is output internally by the plugin.